# Biblatex BibliographyOption with braces?

Tags: biblatex

For a specific biblatex style, I have declared a bibliography option which takes a name, as in

```
\DeclareBibliographyOption{myname}{\edef\somename{#1}}
```

Now LaTeX yields an error if the value of this option consists of braces, such as `myname=M{\"u}ller`:

```
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
\@removeelement #1#2#3->\def \reserved@a ##1,#1,##
                                                  2\reserved@a {##1,##2\rese...

l.59 \ProcessOptions\relax
```

Is there a way to work around this? If not, is there a way to expand a macro in such a way that braces disappear? My aim is to test for string equivalence via `\ifdefstring`, and the test returns false if `M{\"u}ller` is compared to `M\"uller`, as in

```
\edef\x{M{\"u}ller}
\edef\y{M\"uller}
\ifdefstrequal{\x}{\y}{TRUE}{FALSE}
```

which will return `FALSE`.

Comment: Passing `M{\"u}ller` through `\edef` is impossible and it wouldn't solve the problem anyway, because `\edef` doesn't touch braces that don't delimit arguments to commands.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If I pass `M{\"u}ller` to `\edef`, it expands to `M{ü}ller`, which is one step closer to what I want. Why is it "impossible"?

Comment: No, `\"u` expands to the set of instructions for *printing* "ü", which is *very* different from a simple token `ü`. And `\edef\x{\"u}` will *always* raise errors: the command `\"` *cannot* go inside `\edef`.

Comment: Hm, seemed to work good enough for my purpose (I compare two `\edef`ed macros via etoolbox's `\ifdefstrequal`). Now the question is: is there a way to fully expand a string for testing, including macros and nested braces?

Comment: Are the braces you need to strip off just like in `M{\"u}ller` or is there something more complicated?

Comment: Ideally, not only the braces should be stripped, but strings should be tested for equivalence notwithstanding how they were encoded (that's why I hoped for `edef` to fully expand the string). As far as the braces are concerned, it does should not get more complicated (no deeper nesting).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6273/discussion-between-egreg-and-jspitzm)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot log into the chat room :-(

Comment: Try now, it should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `\edef` in this context: `\edef\x{...\"u...}` will *always* fail.

If you are using UTF-8 for your files and your author can appear in the three forms

```
M{\"u}ller
M\"uller
Müller
```

then these macros can be what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\stripbraces#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \def\IeC##1{##1}%
  \protected@edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \gdef\@gtempa{}%
  \expandafter\@stripbraces\@tempa\@nil
  \endgroup
  \let#2\@gtempa
}
\def\@stripbraces#1{%
  \ifx#1\@nil\else
    \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\@gtempa\expandafter{\@gtempa#1}%
    \expandafter\@stripbraces
  \fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\stripbraces{M\"uller}{\x}
\stripbraces{M{\"u}ller}{\y}
\stripbraces{Müller}{\z}

\ifdefstrequal{\x}{\y}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\ifdefstrequal{\x}{\z}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\ifdefstrequal{\y}{\z}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\stripbraces{Øre}{\x}
\stripbraces{{\O}re}{\y}
\stripbraces{\O re}{\z}

\ifdefstrequal{\x}{\y}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\ifdefstrequal{\x}{\z}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\ifdefstrequal{\y}{\z}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\stripbraces{Gauß}{\x}
\stripbraces{Gau{\ss}}{\y}
\stripbraces{Gau\ss}{\z}

\ifdefstrequal{\x}{\y}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\ifdefstrequal{\x}{\z}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\ifdefstrequal{\y}{\z}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\end{document}
```

All the tests yield "TRUE".

However this would fail for `Fran{\c{c}}ais` and `Fran{\c c}ais`. So the final answer depends on your needs.

Comment: Thanks, @egreg, this seems to work for my cases. For some reason, however, it does not work for values passed through `\DeclareBibliographyOption`, which seems to do some expansion. I.e. with `\DeclareBibliographyOption{myname}{\def\myname{#1}}` and `myname=M\"uller` the `\"u` is expanded.

Comment: @JSpitzm Try `\stripbraces{#1}{\myname}` instead of `\def\myname{#1}`

Comment: this fails as well. It seems the `\"u` is already expanded when passed as `#1` within `\DeclareBibliographyOption`.

Comment: @JSpitzm Sorry, but without a real example it's impossible to say more.

Comment: Nevermind, it'll do for now without the bibliography option approach (I'll provide an alternative way to set the respective name). The real example is my biblatex-publist package on CTAN.

Comment: I think the problem with `\DeclareBibliographyOptions` is that is uses the `keyval` package which does not seem to handle things like umlaut macros well (see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.text.tex/x33EMrcAjuQ/discussion).

Answer (score 0):

Trying out unicode bib options with

```
\newcommand\testuni{}
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{test-unicode}[false]{
\ifstrequal{#1}{ຢഓæçøûüŧũǻΦ}{\renewcommand\testuni{ຢഓæçøûüŧũǻΦ has matched}}{\renewcommand\testuni{ຢഓæçøûüŧũǻΦ has not matched}}
}
```

and setting the biblatex option to

```
  test-unicode=ຢഓæçøûüŧũǻΦ,
```

and compiling in xelatex with the file in utf-8 format, and suitable font (`\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\newfontface\funicode{Code2003}`)

```
Result of \textbackslash testuni: {\funicode \testuni}.
```

gives

[image: unicode biblatex bib options]

Changing the bib option to

```
test-unicode=ຢഓæçѾѬøûüŧũǻΦ,
```

produces

[image: unmatched string is correct]

So looks OK now.

The old-style escapes are no longer really needed.