# Specific/Custom cite- and bib-style needed: How to write/edit/program it?

Tags: biblatex

for my philosophical papers at university I need a specific cite- and bibstyle.
I already tried a lot of styles. But since now there was not any that matched my needs. (closest were `authoryear-icomp` and `authortitle-dw` [except I need authoryear]

What I need:

*Cite-Style*
I have primariy and secondary texts that I would like to be quoted like this:

Primary (Lastname, Shorthand, Page)

Secondary (Lastname Year, Page) = normal authoryear.
Important: "ibid" (German: ebd.) has to work.

*Bib-Style*

Primary: Lastname, Initial-of-first-name, (Shorthand) [Year-firstpublished], Title, Address, (p.r.n. Year-of-edition-published).

Secondary: Lastname, Initial-of-first-name, Year, Title, Address = normal authoryear.

My preambel looks the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,ibidpage=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{XYZ.bib}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Bibentries for example:

Primary:

```
@book{DiltheyGSV,
Address = {Stuttgart},
Author = {Dilthey, W.},
Edition = {5},
Keywords = {primlit},
Shorthand = {GS V},
Title = {Die geistige Welt. Einleitung in die Philosophie des Lebens},
Year = {1968}}
```

Secondary:

```
@book{Soboleva2014,
Address = {Wien},
Author = {Soboleva, M.},
Keywords = {seclit},
Title = {Leben und Sein},
Year = {2014}}
```

It would be awesome if anybody could help me, or at least give me hints how to edit the `*.cbx` file (thats the file you need to edit, don't you?)!

Thank you in advance

Comment: I am not certain but I believe that it is currently difficult (not possible?) to use different styles for bibliographies in a single document. Splitting the bibliography is no problem. (See pp 109-110 ish of the manual for one way to do this with keywords of the kind you've defined.) But I don't think there is a way to easily specify separate styles. Maybe you can redefine the relevant macros in the file in between the two bibliographies? That is, print one, redefine, print second?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170358/biblatex-different-bibstyles-in-the-same-document?

Comment: I found a way to "work around" the problem...not very pretty and what I wanted, but okay for the moment - see answer below.

Answer (score 1):

cfr, I had a look into the links and also at some documentaries.

At the moment I do not have the time to fully work out the problem, as i have to write some papers...
At least I figuired out a (more or less good) workaround and want to let you know what I'm doing.

I do not use any cite commands, but type in my references "manually".
Getting entries to the bibliography by `\nocite{xyz}`
For the bibliography, which I split into "Primary" and "Secondary" via keywords I use the following:

```
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{
\iffieldundef{shorthand}{}{
    \printfield{shorthand}\addspace =\addspace}}
```

It is by far not perfect, but okay for the moment...

Comment: (+1) Though I'm not entirely clear why this stops you using ordinary citation commands. Re. the general problem: have you considered putting in a feature request? It seems to me this would be a useful thing for `biblatex` to handle properly ;).

Comment: Maybe I was a little bit unclear/expressed myself wrong. I work around the shorthand/different type of citation problem by using `\textquote[Dilthey, GS VII, S.67]{Blablablabla}`and `\textcquote[vgl.][S. 312]{Soboleva2014}{more blablabla}`. Don't know if thats "professional" but that way I get everything the way I want it printed ;) Yeah - I could propose a feature request for `biblatex` as it would be great to get the work done without any workarounds :D

Comment: Thanks. That helps. And if it works, well... ;) I think a feature request would be good, though, especially since the primary/secondary split is a common requirement.

Comment: I even found an easier way, if you use the prefix like `\textquote[Dilthey,][335]{DiltheyGSV}{blablabla}` -- it does exactly what I need: (Dilthey, GSV, S. 335) :)